# An alternative to the usual technique to search the index of a sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

We know that

$$\lim_n \frac{n^2+4}{n^2+n-1}=1$$

To find the index $\nu$ (or $N$, or $\bar{n}$) I should to solve this disequation with absolute value ($\forall \epsilon>0$)

$$\left|\frac{n^2+4}{n^2+n-1}-1\right|<\epsilon\tag{1}$$
equivalent to
$$\left|\frac{-n+5}{n^2+n-1}\right|<1$$
Now being $|A(n)|<\epsilon \iff -\epsilon<A(n)<\epsilon$, and solving this sisteme:

$$\begin{cases} 
\dfrac{-n+5}{n^2+n-1}>-\epsilon& \\
\dfrac{-n+5}{n^2+n-1}<\epsilon
\end{cases}$$
after a few simple algebraic steps, I find an interval like this:
$$n<-\epsilon-\sqrt{7}\quad \mathrm{or}\quad \:n>\sqrt{7}-\epsilon$$

If I take as $\nu=\max\{\lfloor \sqrt{7}-\epsilon\rfloor,1\}$, surely $n>\nu$. Are these steps (although they are simple) generally necessary for some limits if no appropriate increase is found or can appropriate increases be found in this case or in others sequences?

Comment: Something must be wrong since $\nu$ doesn't get much bigger when $\varepsilon$ gets small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can note that whenever $n\geq 5$, your absolute value simply is the first fraction from below and
$$0\le\frac{n-5}{n^2+n-1}\le\frac{n-5}{n^2}\le\frac1n,$$
which shows that $n\geq \max(5,\frac1\epsilon)\implies |a_n-1|\le\varepsilon$.

Comment: Meanwhile I thank you very much and I voted positively but the numerator is $5-n$. The students do not always understand the meaning of the increases unfortunately and I am obliged to do calculations.

Comment: @Sebastiano Note that the denominator is always positive so for $n\geq 5$ we have $$\left|\frac{5-n}{n^2+n-1}\right|=\frac1{n^2+n-1} \cdot |5-n|=\frac{n-5}{n^2+n-1}.$$

Comment: @Sebastiano Wait, do you mean your students don't know what *less or equal than* means?

Comment: The lesser or equal is understood but the increases no :-(. Unfortunately they are still very mechanical and I have difficulties. They always ask for mechanical rules that lead them to the solution. With correctness I wait for some other answer and eventually there are no others I add +15. I understand that my question has very little interest for the community.

Comment: @Sebastiano Wait, I don't understand what you mean by "increases"  ?

Comment: Excuse me very much:  I'm using the deepl translator. "increase" as "surcharge" or "increment". Now is it clear? :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99314/discussion-between-maximilian-janisch-and-sebastiano).